# Doubt about double limit definition.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, definition

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence. We say that the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$, if for every $\varepsilon >0$ given, there exists $n_0 (\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$$n > n_{0}(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |a_n - L| < \varepsilon $$

Consider $g: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I would like to know how I would write

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left( \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(n,k)\right) = L $$

in terms of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ language.

**My progress**

First, I defined $\bar{g}(n)$ as $ \bar{g}(n) := \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} g(n,k) $ . So fixing $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for every $\varepsilon/2 >0$ exists $k(n,\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$, satisfying

$$k > k(n,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |g(n,k) - \bar{g}(n)| < \varepsilon/2.$$

On the other hand $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bar{g}(n) = L$. Consequently for every $\varepsilon/2 >0,$ exists $n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N},$ satisfying

$$n > n_0(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |\bar{g}(n) - L| < \varepsilon/2 $$

Therefore, joining the two results above we have that the definition of the double limit would be:

For every $\varepsilon>0,$ exists $n_0(\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, and for every $n> n_0(\varepsilon)$, exists $k(n,\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, such that

$$n> n_0(\varepsilon),\hspace{0.1cm} k>k(n,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |g(n,k) - L| < \varepsilon.  $$

Is this  correct? I'm not confident with my result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am to understand that you are motivating the definition with the first part of your effort?  The standard definition for convergence of a doubly indexed sequence is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $n,k >N$ we have $|g(n,k)-L|<\epsilon$.  So you are on the right track, but you only need a single integer $N$.

Comment: Are you sure about this definition? For example if we define $g(n,k) = n/k$ then  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(n,k) = 0$, but we can't find $N$, satisfying $n,k > N$ $\Rightarrow$ $|n/k | < 1/2$.

Comment: Your example does not have a limit.  I will show this by finding two subsequences that converge to different values: First $g(1,k) \to 0$ (as you noted).  But $g(k,k) \to 1$.  You are evaluating marginal limits, and it is not always true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\lim_{k \to \infty} g(n,k)) = \lim_{k \to \infty}(\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n,k)) = \lim_{n,k \to \infty} g(n,k)$.  If convergence holds with the definition I gave, then this equality does hold.

Comment: I'm not doing $\lim_{n,k \rightarrow \infty} g(n,k)$. My question is how I write by  limit definition the equation $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } g(n,k))$

Comment: In that case, your definition for convergence of marginal limits looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm confused: without knowing what is the definition of the expression $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(n,k) = L $, how did you come up with the expression? One can give whatever definition to an unknown expression.

Comment: I tryed to explain how I come up with the expression, on the part below of "My Effort"

Comment: If one wants to **prove** something, one must have a statement first. "how I write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(n,k) = L$ using the definition above?" is *not* a mathematical statement. I don't  understand what "My Effort" means.

Comment: On the other hand It is a legitimate question to ask how does one interpret/define the notation $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} g(n,k) = L$.

Comment: Assuming one knows $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} g(n,k) $ is **defined**  as $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} g(n,k)\right) $$ (provided it exists) one might want to ask "how would I write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} g(n,k) =L$ in terms of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language."

Comment: I change the text of the question, sorry about my english and thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, <s>I defined</s>`define` $\bar{g}(n)$ as 
>   $$
>  \bar{g}(n) := \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} g(n,k). 
> $$
>    (I supposed that the limits always exists just to try to understand what is happening). So fixing $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for every $\varepsilon/2 >0$ exists $k_0(n,\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$, satisfying
>   $$
> k > k_0(n,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |g(n,k) - \bar{g}(n)| < \varepsilon/2.
> $$
>   On the other hand $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bar{g}(n) = L$. Consequently for every $\varepsilon/2 >0,$ exists $n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N},$ satisfying
>   $$
> n > n_0(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |\bar{g}(n) - L| < \varepsilon/2 
> $$
>
> Therefore, joining the two results above we have <s>`that the definition of the double limit would be`</s>:
>
> For every $\varepsilon>0,$ `there` exists $n_0(\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, and for every $n> n_0(\varepsilon)$, `there` exists $k_0(n,\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, such that
>   $$
> n> n_0(\varepsilon),\hspace{0.1cm} k>k_0(n,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |g(n,k) - L| < \varepsilon.  
> $$

`It looks good.`

---

The limit in your question is called "[repeated limit](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Repeated_limit)", not the ["double limit"](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Double_limit).

Comment: Very precise and exactly fixing the issues with OP's presentation. +1

Comment: *Here's a comment (Initially posted as an answer) from @user201900 regarding your answer*: The definition below (proposed by Matheus) is different than the definition of repeated limits since existence of the limit $\bar{g}(n)$ is not required. Does anyone know if this type of limit has a name and a specific notation? 

For every $\varepsilon>0,$ `there` exists $n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$, and for every $n>n_0(\varepsilon)$, `there` exists $k_0(n,\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
$$n> n_0(\varepsilon),\hspace{0.1cm} k>k_0(n,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |g(n,k) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @projectilemotion: The quoted condition is indeed not equivalent to the repeated limit but a consequence of it. To the best of my knowledge, there is no specific notation for it.