# The limit of a limsup of a nonnegative sequence is 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I am currently looking at a result that states, for some nonnegative function $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, there exists a constant $c> 0$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \limsup_{n \to \infty} |g(n,k) - c | = 0. ~(*)
\end{align}
It seems to me that the $\limsup$ is unnecessary, and could have been replaced by a $\lim$. This is because I believe that the above equation states that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists K_{\epsilon}$ such that $\forall k > K_{\epsilon}, \exists N_{k, \epsilon}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sup_{n > N_{k,\epsilon}} |g(n,k) - c| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
(I found a nice explanation of the meaning of a double limit in quantifiers here [Doubt about double limit definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420691/doubt-about-double-limit-definition) ).

Doesn't the $\sup$ imply that $|g(n,k) - c| < \epsilon|$ for all $n > N_{k,\epsilon}$, and vice versa? Also, is there any difference between $(*)$ and the following:
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to\infty} \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n,k)}{c} = \lim_{k \to\infty} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n,k)}{c} = 1
\end{align}
? Thanks so much.

Comment: As an answer to my first question, it is noted in the comments of @Jack 's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420691/doubt-about-double-limit-definition?noredirect=1&lq=1 that the \epsilon-\delta formulation of the repeated limit is not a definition but a consequence, and it does not imply the existence of the interior limit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(n,k)=\frac12+\frac1{k^2+5} \cos(\pi n)$ and $c=\frac12$. It satisfies the condition, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert g(n,k)-c\rvert$ does not exist for any $k$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the counter-example! However, I was more interested in the error in my \delta-\epsilon description, as well as the comparison with the last aligned equation in my question.